# Congruences and solution repeat intervals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I'm teaching myself about congruences, and I've done quite a few examples, but the answers to two problems have me confused.

I understand $$3x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x=4+7t$$  A solution comes every 7 digits, which makes sense since 7 is the modulus.

I understand $$6x \equiv 9 \pmod{15}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x=4+5t$$  A solution comes every 5 digits, which fits with $\frac{m}{d}=\frac{15}{3}=5$, where $m$ is the modulus and $d$ is the GCD of $a$ and $m$ [$a \equiv b \pmod{m}$]. The repeat interval of 5 is one third the original modulus 15, but the GCD explains this.

*However*, these next two problems have repeat intervals of half the modulus, but I don't know why.  $$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{32}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x \equiv 1, 15, 17, 31 \pmod{32},$$ but these can be written as $x=1+16t$ and $x=15+16t$.  16 is half the modulus 32.  Where is this factor of 2 entering the problem? The exponent?  Not all quadratic congruences do this though...

A similar thing happens with $$5x^2-2x-3 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}\quad \Rightarrow\quad x \equiv 1, 3, 7, 9 \pmod{12},$$ but these can be written as $x=1+6t$ and $x=3+6t$.  6 is half the modulus 12.  Again, I don't see where the factor of 2 enters the problem.

I've tried browsing ahead in my book to see if there's some explanation.  Am I missing some fundamental property of congruences?  (Note: if the answer is beyond my level, feel free to let me know, and I'll patiently work to build my knowledge.)

Comment: Part of the mystery about the quadratic congruences is that when $x \equiv r \bmod N$ solves $x^2 \equiv a \bmod N$, then so will $x \equiv -r \bmod N$.  Indeed when modulus $N \gt 2$ is a prime, then nonzero $a$ will either have no "square root" or else two distinct "square roots" modulo $N$.  Also the quadratic formula "works" for odd prime modulus $N$.

Comment: Consider $x^2\equiv a \pmod{2^k}$, say $k\ge 3$. If $x$ is a solution then so is $x+2^{k-1}$, for $(x+2^{k-1})^2=x^2+2x(2^{k-1})+2^{2k-2}\equiv x^2\pmod{2^{k}}$.

Comment: Andre Nicolas, your example is the most helpful idea (at a level I can vaguely grasp) that I've come across regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions to $x^2=a$ mod $m$ is not an easy problem. I'd recommend you look up Quadratic Reciprocity, the Chinese Remainder theorem, and the Jacobi Symbol

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.  Clearly, there are some complex fundamentals underlying such superficially simple problems.

Comment: @DBS that sounds like a solid summary of Number Theory in general.